# Fastest polygon union when all polygons are rectangles?

Tags: python, algorithm, geospatial, geopandas, shapely

At my job we have to union many polygons together for some spatial aggregation. One problem we have is limited runtime and memory constraints (aws lambda), so for larger feature collections our current geopandas implementations hit their limits.

My main question is: is there a faster polygon union / algorithm I could be using other than shapely unary union (which i assume is what geopandas dissolve is using), that could take advantage of the fact that all polygons are rectangles, with no holes. (I.e. hoping that unary union having to account for arbitrary shapes may leave performance on the table)

Comment: Are they all axis-aligned rectangles? I think that will allow for much simpler algorithms than arbitrarily rotated rectangles.

Comment: Are these rectangles aligned to a grid? If so, you may be able to save memory and space using a [raster representation](https://datacarpentry.org/organization-geospatial/01-intro-raster-data/).

Comment: I’d give geopandas dissolve a try. It uses a different memory model than collections of shapely objects, and might be faster. Not sure though. The speed will likely come down to algorithmic efficiency against compiled routines. So the answers to the above comments questions will matter a lot I expect.

Comment: @moreON - they are not all axis aligned, no

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm doesn't really use the rectangular property of items.

The initial process is to create additional points for each intersection  : in case of intersection between two rectangle sides, side(s) may be split in 2 or more polygon segment.

The next step consist in finding the top left point of all polygons and
assume that the virtual previous point is at the left of this point.

To find the next point of the envelope, choose among all polygons sharing  the current point, the vector CN (current point to next point) whose angle CP^CN is the maximum.

When next point is top left point, it is completed.

Process all points and remove those that are inside the envelope(s).
If there are remaining points, use the same algorithm to find other envelopes (archipelago case).

For performance issues, I recommend to have a relation between points and the list of [polygon, point index] to which points belong.